# Is the use of "can" before the subject correct or acceptable here?

Tags: modal-verbs

I found the following in a user review of the movie Kissing Jessica Stein:

> The easy chat they have overcomes Jessica repulsion at the whole idea and soon they have become more than just friends. ***However can Jessica accept the truth herself far less be honest with others.***
>
> ([Source](https://www.imdb.com/review/rw1235642/?ref_=tt_urv))

Is the use of "can" before the subject correct or acceptable here? Doesn't it turn the phrase into a question? The correct wouldn't be to say something like:

*However Jessica can't accept the truth herself far less be honest with others*

Comment: Sounds like an asserted question given as a statement of opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does make it a question, and the passage is very badly punctuated. It should be like this:

> The easy chat they have overcomes Jessica's repulsion at the whole idea, and soon they have become more than just friends. However, can Jessica accept the truth herself, far less be honest with others?

Note the **'s** after the first "Jessica" and the comma after "idea". In the second sentence, note the comma after "However", the comma after "herself", and the question mark added at the end.
Bad punctuation can make these sentences hard to read for non-native speakers.